# How to properly reuse EE module more then once

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

From https://medium.com/google-earth/making-it-easier-to-reuse-code-with-earth-engine-script-modules-2e93f49abb13 I'm learning how to use modules.

So I can have `mdl1`:

```
var timeField = 'system:time_start';
exports.timeField = timeField;
```

Then on `mdl2` I can:

```
var mdl1 = require('users/user/rs:mdl1');
```

Then I have `mdl3` which required `mdl2`:

```
var mdl2 = require('users/user/rs:mdl2');
```

What if I need `mdl1` on `mdl3` as well, should I do the following on `mdl3` again?

```
var mdl1 = require('users/user/rs:mdl1');
```

I put a `print("module numnber")` on each module and looks like the require call actually executes the script, I think by doing like above I'm executing `mdl1` two times, which looks wrong. Isn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modules in Earth Engine work a little like Python modules (if you are familiar with using Python). You won't need to call/require `mdl1` again within `mdl3` as long as you export the `mdl1` object within `mdl2`. I think this should get the result you are looking for.

`mdl1` module:

```
var timeField = 'system:time_start';
exports.timeField = timeField;
```

`mdl2` module:

```
var mdl1 = require('users/user/rs:mdl1');
exports.mdl1 = mdl1
```

`mdl3` module:

```
var mdl2 = require('users/user/rs:mdl2');
var field = mdl2.mdl1.timeField
print(field)
```

This will prevent `mdl1` from being executed twice and will allow you to access the variables. I hope this helps!